# Unit Testing Arduino ESP8266 in CI (Native) with libraries

Tags: c++, continuous-integration, platformio, unity-test-framework

I am using an Arduino `ESP8266` with `platformio`. I am adding Unit Testing with the `Unity` framework and I want to run the tests in Gitlab `CI`. In my project, I use other libraries, such as `ESP8266WiFi`.

I am using the `Native` platform to run tests and my **platformio.ini** file looks like this:

```
[platformio]
default_envs = esp01

[env]
lib_deps = 
    dancol90/ESP8266Ping@^1.0

[env:esp01]
platform = espressif8266
framework = arduino
board = esp01
; Serial Monitor options
monitor_speed = 115200

[env:native]
; Testing without HW in CI, I am using this
platform = native
lib_deps = 
    ${env.lib_deps}
    fabiobatsilva/ArduinoFake@^0.3.1
; Coverage:
lib_compat_mode = off
build_src_filter = +<*> -<*dirs*> -<to/> -<exclude/>
build_flags =
  -lgcov
  --coverage
extra_scripts = ci/test_coverage.py
```

My **test** would be something like this:

```
#include <unity.h>
#include "data.h"

void test_1(void) {
  uint8_t mode = get_value();
  TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL(mode, 0);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    UNITY_BEGIN();

    RUN_TEST(test_1);

    return UNITY_END();
}
```

My simplified **code** would be (data.cpp file):

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

uint8_t mode = 0;
uint8_t get_value(){
  return mode;
}
```

The compilation is working fine with `pio run`.
I am running this command to run the tests:

```
pio test -e native -vvv
```

The error is:

```
test\test_main.cpp:2:25: fatal error: ESP8266WiFi.h: No such file or directory
```

Maybe `ArduinoFake` can't emulate this library? Or should I include the library somehow? Or can't I Unit Test the way I am trying to do it?

If I have this test without importing my code, the test passes:

```
#include <unity.h>
// #include "data.h"

void test_1(void) {
  //uint8_t mode = get_value();
  TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL(0, 0);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    UNITY_BEGIN();

    RUN_TEST(test_1);

    return UNITY_END();
}
```

Comment: Does it run locally? If yes, you may want to compare what is different in CI environment than local.

Comment: No, it doesn't run locally

Comment: First you should run locally before setting up things in CI.

Comment: Yes, it's what I am doing, but the issue has nothing to do with the CI. It was a justification for why I am using the "native" platform. I have to mock or create a simple fake library. But then one of the libraries is using other libraries and is a headache just to do a super simple test. In my opinion unit tests have to be done always and I think is usual to use libraries, and I can't find out a not super complicated solution to a basic problem many people should have faced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is recommended in the [official documentation](https://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/advanced/unit-testing/structure/shared-code.html), the code should be encapsulated in different components. And some components should not depend on exterior libraries, like that I could add unit tests of some of the components.